# How to disable auto zoom in quill editor from react native package?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, quill, react-native-webview

I am trying to integrate quill editor in my react-native application. I am using
**react-native-webview-quilljs** package for this.

https://github.com/reggie3/react-native-webview-quilljs

```
<WebViewQuillJS
   defaultContent="sdfsd"
   backgroundColor={"#FAEBD7"}
/>
```

The problem I am facing is the editor is zooming in when I click on editor to type. This behaviour is taking some part of the editor from the right side off the screen and have to scroll. This behaviour is seen only in iOS platform but not in Android.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around which might not be a good way.
In index.html from the path given bellow, I changed the meta tag

```
node_modules > react-native-webview-quilljs > assets > index.html
```

from this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
```

to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

if there is any other solution, would be welcome

Comment: thanks a lot it helped me with react js as well for react quill